# Good way to code if (var=x) {var=y} atomicly?

Tags: c++, concurrency

Given this function:

```
#include <mutex>

std::mutex mut;
bool data_being_processed=false;


void process_data() {
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mut);

    if (data_being_processed == false) {
        data_being_processed = true;

        // Process data

        data_being_processed = false;
    }
}
```

My understanding is that process_data will not be executed by more than one thread simultaneously. Is it efficient though? Is there a better way to do if (var=x) {var=y} atomically?

Comment: Consider making `data_being_processed` an atomic value, or a  `std::condition_variable`

Comment: Your mutex should already lock, so that no other thread can do the same process. There's no reason for an extra check. That's "mutex" stands for: "Mutual exclusion"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`std::atomic`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic) makes this fairly easy:

```
#include <atomic>

std::atomic<bool> data_being_processed{false};

void process_data() {
    bool value = false;
    if (data_being_processed.compare_exchange_weak(value, true)) {
        // Process data
        data_being_processed = false;
    }
}
```

`compare_exchange_weak` sets the `data_being_processed` to `true` if it currently matches `value` (`false`), if it matches and sets the value it returns `true` otherwise it sets `value` to `true` and returns `false`.

Answer (score 2):

> My understanding is that process_data will not be executed by more than one thread simultaneously.

That's correct.

> Is it efficient though? Is there a better way to do if (var=x) {var=y} atomically?

That part could be done more efficiently by using a `std::atomic<bool>` or `std::atomic_flag`.

Example:

```
#include <atomic>

void process_data() {
    static std::atomic_flag data_being_processed = ATOMIC_FLAG_INIT;

    if(not data_being_processed.test_and_set()) {

        std::cout << "processing data\n";

        data_being_processed.clear();
    } else {
        std::cout << "data is already being processed\n";
    }
}
```

However, this changes the program flow. In your original code, a second thread entering the function would wait until the lock could be acquired and in my example it would simply skip processing the data.

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to elaborate my comment. As stated, "mutex" stands for "mutual exclusion". This means that while a mutex is locked, no other process can use it. All other caller will have to wait until the mutex is unlocked. Example:

```cpp
#include<mutex>
#include<iostream>
#include<chrono>
#include<thread>

static std::mutex mut;

void process_data(int i) {
    std::scoped_lock lock{mut};
    std::cout << "start " << i << "...";
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));
    std::cout << "end " << i << '\n';
}

int main() {
    std::thread t1(process_data, 1);
    std::thread t2(process_data, 2);
    std::thread t3(process_data, 3);
    t1.join();
    t2.join();
    t3.join();
}
```

will return (for example)

```
start 1...end 1
start 3...end 3
start 2...end 2
```